# Can a github repository be part of multiple organizations?

Tags: github, repository

On GitHub, a user can belong to multiple organizations. Is it possible for a repository to be part of multiple organizations as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this blog post by GitHub](https://github.blog/2010-06-29-introducing-organizations/), a repository can only belong to one organization.

> Creating an organization helps you centralize your organization’s code. All repositories live under the organization, and billing goes through a central organization account.

You can fork one organization's repository into another organization's space, but the original belongs to just a single organization.